# Copy paste files stuck at "Estimating time remaining..."

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, copy-paste

I'm using a Macbook Pro retina with macOS Sierra. The Macbook is just a few weeks old. Only recently, whenever I try to compress, or paste a folder, it will stuck at estimating time remaining.

[image]

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to restart your MacBook?

Comment: Yep. Same problem

Comment: Using cp in terminal still works find though

Comment: Restarting computer did work for me. This must have been a Finder bug.